# How to seal conduit at utility pole?

Tags: electrical

I want to run an 2” PVC conduit underground from my house to the utility pole for a fiber internet line. The fiber installer said I can leave the end open as in this photo, about 2ft off the ground. I do see this kind of install all the time, but I don’t like that it fill up with rain. What’s the best way to seal this opening?
I thought of a weatherhead cap but I’ve never seen one of these installed on a utility pole so close to the ground.

Comment: Just put a u-bend at the top of the conduit and loop the fiber back up from there?

Comment: A U bend adds 180 degrees of bending to the pull. A weatherhead cap pops off so it's a straight pull, then you snap the cap back on once the pull is done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The conduit will be full of water anyway, so that doesn't matter (it will fill from condensation if nothing else) as all cable/wire/fiber to be used in outside conduits is rated to be sitting in water its entire life.

Image removed for draconian attribution idiocy

The proper fitting is a "weatherhead" and the fiber should be installed with a "drip loop" below that (so water running down the fiber drips off, rather than running into the conduit.) Also, it prevents sharp bends at the weatherhead entrance. Normally that should be placed at least 8 feet off the ground, so run your conduit up that far.

You should also have an expansion fitting at the house and at the pole to allow for frost movement without breaking the conduit, unless you live in a non-freezing area.

If you are just going to run it up 2 feet, buy a pound of duct seal (from the electrical aisle or supply, not the HVAC section) and pack that in around it - but I guarantee you, it will be full of water within a month unless you are in a very dry desert location.

Comment: In addition, any buried conduit needs to be considered "wet" no matter what's in it and how well it's sealed, so you need to make sure that whatever is in the conduit is wet-rated for continual water contact.

Comment: @Milwrdfan that's literally covered in the first sentence...

Comment: The weatherhead also discourages squirrels, rats and mice from entering the conduit.

Comment: Wow, interesting! I didn’t know all outdoor cables are safe to be submerged long term. Is that true of 240V AC power lines too?

Comment: **Every** outdoor conduit is **defined** as a **wet** location. Virtually all of them meet the definition. Yes, it applies to 240V and 600V and 1200V wires and cables as well. This why it's important that you use a wire with a "wet" rating when running in oudoor conduit, and is one of several reasons what putting NM/B in outdoor conduit is both stupid and forbidden (it's not wet-rated - it also has terrible fill.) In my own field I've seen the edu-ma-cationally challenged put indoor-type network cables (and fibers) in outdoor conduits, and I've seen them fail.

Comment: @ElliottB Yes, it has to be that way. You cannot keep water out of conduit.  I heard a story of an installer who ran hundreds of feet of conduit at a race track across the track and a berm. As such, air blew through the pipe, which they didn't bother to seal because they'd be there the next day. They pumped out 20 gallons of water.  The air was humid and the ground was cool.